# Probability of at least 2 boys and at least one of them is the youngest in a family of 3.

Tags: probability

In a randomly chosen family with three children of different ages, what is the probability that at least two of the children are boys, given that at least one of the two youngest children is a boy?

I have arrived at an answer of 3/8. 8 coming from there are 8 total possible cases a family can be formed. And there are only 3 cases where the youngest child is a boy from a tree diagram. Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: That;'s too low.  If the eldest is a boy (prob .5) then you know you have a success, so the answer must be $>.5$

Answer (score 1):

For a family with $3$ children, we initially have $8$ possibilities (with youngest first and oldest last):

$$
BBB, BBG, BGB, BGG, GBB, GBG, GGB, GGG.
$$

Now, you are told that at least one of the two youngest children is a boy. Thus, we have only the following $6$ possibilities:

$$
BBB, BBG, BGB, BGG, GBB, GBG.
$$

Of these possibilities, $4$ of them have at least $2$ boys. Thus, the probability you seek is 
$$
4/6=2/3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first think about the two youngest.  Since at least one is a boy the three, equally likely, cases are $BB,GB,BG$.  Thus there is a $\frac 13$ probability that both of the youngest are boys, and a $\frac 23$ probability that exactly one is.

To have at least two boys out of the three, we either need both youngest to be boys or exactly one to be a boy AND the eldest to be a boy.  Thus the answer is $$\frac 13+\frac 23\times \frac 12=\frac 23$$